# How to do a specific operation to only certain fields in a Java object or a JSON payload

Tags: java, json, annotations, pojo

I have a spring boot microservices application and within it, I want to do a specific operation (say some string manip) on specific fields of a Java object (or a JSON object).

For example:

```
class Employee {

private String id;
private String name;
private String someOtherId;

}
```

If I need to do a specific operation only to id and someOtherId fields, how can go about it? Can there be custom annotations created to handle this?

Something like:

stringAppend(employee) should do this operation to only the specific fields. I don't want to check iteratively inside the function, rather I would do it via configuration.

The object will be a payload from a HTTPRequest and need to do this manipulation specifically to only certain fields.

Comment: Your question is not clear. What kind of transformation you want to perform on given object? In scenario: client sends `JSON` payload, `Jackson` deserialises it to `Employee` object, you do `String` manipulation - what do you mean by `I don't want to check iteratively inside the function, rather I would do it via configuration.`?Also, how do you choose for which fields in `Employee` class you will do manipulations?

Comment: That's my question after all. -- "Also, how do you choose for which fields in Employee class you will do manipulations? "

I can have custom annotations to identify which fields to do manipulations and perform the manipulation for each field iteratively through generics and reflections. 

Is there a better alternative?

Answer (score 1):

For manipulating the specific fields of received object in HTTP request payload, you can use Jackson library in Java. Jackson is a very popular and efficient java based library to serialize or map java objects to JSON and vice versa.

In this case from http request body, Employee object will be in serialized formed.
To deserialized it to actual Employee object you can use ObjectMapper from Jackson library as follows :

Assume `payloadJson` is a string which contains request payload in JSON format.

`ObjectMapper objectMapper = new ObjectMapper();`

`Employee employee = objectMapper.readValue(payloadJson, Employee.class);`

After desrialization you can perform manipulation on fields of Employee object using Getters and Setters method.

Comment: Thanks Sagar. But mapping from JSON to object wasn't the ask. ObjectMapper will do it. My question was, after having the object, I need to perform an operation only to certain fields. There should be some way for this to be handled in one go, rather than doing it iteratively.